# WGS1984 to GDA 94 Zone 50 in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, australia

I am using Arcmap.

I have always defined the projection before starting a map.
I have created a map in WGS 1984  and it is complete. They now want the map in GDA94 Zone 50.
When I change the projection in the coordinate system it just seems to give me degree's minutes seconds and won't work.

Normally I would always just create a new map with the new projection and drag everything in.

I am time poor and there is a lot in this map.

Is it possible to change the projection without making a new map?

When I go into Coordinate system > and define the MGA projection there doesn't appear to be one from WGS to GDA. Just from GDA to WGS...

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to change the coordinate systems of your layers (feature classes) or of your map?  The question says map, but some of the discussion looks like the layers.  To change it for the map, just right-click the data frame object in the table of contents (usually "Layers" at the top), then select "Properties" and click on the "Coordinate System" tab.  Then select the coordinate system you want there.  That should be all that's required to change the coordinate system of the map.  The layers will be automatically reprojected on-the-fly if required.

Comment: Secondly, if you want to select a specific transformation (instead of letting it choose automatically), the transformations are bi-directional.  So the title says one way, but they actually work both ways.

Comment: If you're talking about the status bar (bottom of the UI), you can change those coordinates on the General tab (I think) via the "display units".